# Getting error while connect connected registry in Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-container-registry

I tried on-premises synchronizes container images by using *Connected Registry* in **Azure Container Registry**.

And I followed ACR documentation to create a setup (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/quickstart-deploy-connected-registry-iot-edge-cli)

1. [Getting error while deploying the modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EBzt.png)
2. [Troubleshoot - Container Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJx3S.png)
3. [ACR Token Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjfcD.png)
4. [ACR Scope Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tm3a.png)

getting insufficient scope error. But I gave **ReadWrite** permission for all the repositories. Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check if you have given the permissions `content/read , content/write` scopes for the required registry for repository push , which I hope you have already done if the repo is present.

[image]

2. If the permissions are configured properly , please check if the admin user is enabled .

The scopes may also refer to the actual role permission to operate

For the Azure Container Registry, you may log in  in two ways.
One - Using the command `az acr login` -n azureacrServer -u username -p password. Then you have the owner permission after logging in.

The other one is that log in with a **service principal** using the command `docker login` azureacrServer -u servicePrincipalId -p sppassword. In this way, you just have the permission of the service principal after logging in

Please check

[Registry authentication options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication?tabs=azure-cli#service-principal) and  [container registry repository scoped permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-repository-scoped-permissions)

**References:**

1. [Quickstart - Create connected registry using the portal - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/quickstart-connected-registry-portal#create-a-connected-registry-resource-for-read-and-write-functionality)
2. [Pull images from a connected registry - Azure Container Registry | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/pull-images-from-connected-registry#create-a-scope-map)